# "Script" Category under Scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools

I am and inspecting a simple script's execution context in chrome dev tools. I noticed on a breakpoint or debugger statement, chrome dev tools displays a new category in the scope section. It has:

- Local
- Script
- Global

I believe script has to do with how `let` and `const` are stored, since they are not attached to the global window object. However, my understanding is that they are still in the "global scope" but not bound to the global object.

I believe the "Script" label is representing this idea, but why is the name "script" chosen?

I checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#scope) but unfortunately, it doesn't mention what "Script" is.

Here is a screenshot of my example:

[image]

Does anyone have any insight on the naming convention used?

Comment: It seems like the only person who could answer "why is the name "script" chosen?" is the person who actually wrote the PR for Chrome DevTools. If you're looking for someone to validate your understanding of its behavior, that seems like a separate question. It would be good to clarify what type of answer you're actually expecting.

Comment: I assume it's because the language distinguishes between (ordinary) scripts and modules.

Comment: I have check this in FireFox as well and the scopes FireFox creates are 1) Test 2) Block 3) Global. I think they need to name scopes more preciously to make things clear

Answer (score 1):

Because variables in the scirpt scope can be accessed in another script tag(including the external ones).

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685277/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-script-scope).

By the way, the Firefox's devtools simply call such a scope "block".
For example:

```
var a = 0;
let b = 1;
function test() {
  function test2() {
    let c = 2;
  }
  test2();
}
test();
```

will look like this in Chrome devtools:
[in Chrome devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA7J7.png)
and looks like this in Firefox devtools:
[in Firefox devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P45qb.png)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, Let and const are stored in seperate memory space and not in the global memory. This seperate memory space here is shown in script section.

Extra : Let and const are **hoisted** and get memory in **seperate memory space** but till they are initialized, they are said to be in "**Temporal Dead Zone**"

Example :

```js
console.log(x); // line1
.
.
.
let x = 10; // line20
console.log(x); // line21
```

Here in Line1 : x got hoisted and got memory space but is uninitialized

In line20 : x got initialized

So between line 1 to line 20 : x is said to be in **temporal dead zone** and will give error if tried to access.