# How can we define Script Scope in javaScript, how it is different from block scope

Tags: javascript

I am basically a bit confused about script scope. I have read about a block, global Scope later I came across **script** scope and I didn't quite get that. If someone can  explain.

Thanks

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Seems like it would if the only answer there actually answered the question, but to my eyes it doesn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's disappointing. Maybe it would be worth reopening this question then?

Comment: *"later I came across script scope"* Where did you come across that? I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Or find the answer and post it there. :-)

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I've [done that now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70786086/157247).