# How to look JavaScript Internal Property "[[Scopes]]"?

Tags: javascript, closures, google-chrome-devtools

I couldn't find the [[Scopes]] on a function object in the chrome console.

```
const secureBooking = function () {
  let passengerCount = 0;
  return function () {
    passengerCount++;
    console.log(`${passengerCount} passengers`);
  };
};
const booker = secureBooking();
console.dir(booker);
```

I am looking for [[Scopes]] property to see closure. But I couldn't find it. I'm sure I've seen it before.

Does anyone know what my issue is?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think you *should* see it?

Comment: What do you mean by "look"? In your code? In your debugging environment? Separately, note that there **is** no `[[Scopes]]` "property" in [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/). V8 has something I *think* I've seen shown as `[[Scopes]]` in VS Code's debugger, though I can't find it now (it may have confused people enough that the display of its information was updated). VS Code's debugger does show closures, if that's what you're looking for, as should any half-decent JavaScript debugger.

Comment: It looks like [[Scopes]] was [removed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1365858).

Comment: @Teemu - Nice find. If you `console.dir` a function that isn't at global scope, you'll see `[[Scopes]]` in Node v18 but not Node v19 (if using the VS Code debugger console). (Finally found where I'd see it, which was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685277/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-script-scope).)

Comment: @PetriHeva You can currently find the closured variables [by setting a breakpoint](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/#scope).

Comment: @Teemu Please make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[Scopes]] is not an internal JavaScript property, it's a feature created by Chromium debugger. As mentioned in the comments, this feature [was removed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1365858) from the `dir` tree. [The same information is available](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/#scope) in Scope tab of the debugger during a breakpoint pause.

Edit on April 4 2023. [[Scopes]] is re-enabled in Chromium debugger.